Error when creating a AuthContext.js file in REACT VITE
enter image description here
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. If you are using JSX, make sure to name the file with the .jsx or .tsx extension.
C:/Users/vince/OneDrive/Desktop/Capstone System/project/src/context/AuthContext.js:92:0
I hope someone will fix it

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
